# How to match all keywords after slash using preg_match and Regex?

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

here are my possible matching cases

```
/aaa
/aaa/
/aaa/bbb
/aaa/bbb/
/aaa/bbb/ccc
/aaa/bbb/ccc/
```

I'm trying to catch `aaa`, `bbb` and `ccc` if available

I know or sure `aaa` is there, so the regex can be `/(aaa)/([^/]*)...`

I tried a few other scenarios to catch the rest of the words after slash, non-greedy `/([^/]+)`, `/([^/].+?)`, `(/[^/].+?)`, `(?:/(.*))` but they don't match all cases.

Any ideas?

One can test here [enter link description here](http://www.phpliveregex.com/)

Comment: Why not just split by `/`?

Comment: Or try using [**`(?:/(aaa)|(?!\A)\G/(\w+))`**](https://regex101.com/r/C7QuVh/1)

Comment: Can't use split in my case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this regex with all optional matches after first match:

```
~^/([^/]+)(?:/([^/]+)(?:/([^/]+))?)?/?$~m
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/Zipw5q/6)

**RegEx Breakup:**

- `^/` - Match `/` at start
- `(` - Start captured group #1

  - `[^/]+` - Match h1 or more non-slash characters
- `)` - End captured group #1
- `(?:` - Start non-capturing group #1

  - `/` - Match a literal slash
  - `(` - Start captured group #2

    - `[^/]+` - Match 1 or more non-slash characters
  - `)` - End captured group #2
  - `(?:` - Start non-capturing group #2

    - `/` - Match literal `/`
    - `(` - Start captured group #3

      - `[^/]+` - Match 1 or more non-slash characters
    - `)` - End captured group #3
  - `)?` - End non-capturing group #2 (optional match)
- `)?` - End non-capturing group #1 (optional match)
- `/?` - Match optional trailing `/`
  `$` - End of input

---

**EDIT:** If you want to match all the components separated by `/` then you can use:

```
~(?:^|\G)/([^/\n]+)~m
```

[RegEx Demo 2](https://regex101.com/r/Zipw5q/7)